# Switch from AMD Integrated GPU to Nvidia Discreet GPU on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, external-monitor

Im running ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3. The problem is when using ubuntu I cant connect my laptop to external monitor but its works perfect when I'm on Windows 10. I check the about of my System and it shows **Graphics - AMD@Renoir **

I already checked the drivers it installed the recommended one its Nvidia 470
I already checked the prime profiles it shows Nvidia too.

How to switch from AMD to Nvidia GPU. I think its using the integrated GPU thats why I cant connect to my external monitor.

Comment: It's best if you would edit your question and include more details. Because if the driver is already installed, what are you asking? What is preventing you from connecting the display?  How are you connecting it and what is the exact problem you encounter?

Comment: Reboot to apply.

Comment: Already updated the question. Now I got the problem all of my drivers are gone. Cant connect to the internet. Is there a way to revert the changes?